# Count total number of callers?

Tags: sql

I'm currently doing this query to find the guy who makes the most calls:

```
SELECT 
    `commenter_name`, 
    COUNT(*) AS `calls` 
FROM `comments` 
GROUP BY `commenter_name` 
ORDER BY `calls` LIMIT 1
```

What I want now is to be able to find out how many total unique callers. I tried using `DISTINCT` but I didn't get anywhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT 'commenter_name') FROM 'comment';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT `commenter_name` FROM `comments`
```

Comment: OP wants `how many total unique callers` and not each unique caller

Answer (score 0):

Select Count(*) From (Select DISTINCT commenter_name from comment) as CmtCnt;